# How can I see the view hierarchy in any app download from appstore while using Xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging

I download and installed some great app from App Store. And I like to see the view hierarchy of the app just for studying.

Is it possible? 
How about using a jailbreak iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with Xcode.

But with a jailbroken iPhone you might be able to use [Reveal](http://revealapp.com). But I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try.